# UIImage Flip and Mirror

Tags: iphone, ios, image, sdk, flip

I have a UIImage I need to Flip and Mirror. I have done this by using a UIImageView. I have two problems with this.

1. This does not change the image only the view. So, when I use the image it is not flipped or i get an error.
2. If I use the same transform two times it does nothing on the second time.

Code Example: ( I am new to IOS programing and am sorry for any bad code.)

Calling the Flip:

```
// ImageHolder is a UIImageView
ImageHolder = [self flip:ImageHolder FlipType:@"V"];
```

What it calls:

```
- (UIImageView *)flip:(UIImageView *) fvImageView FlipType:(NSString *)FlipType { 

    UIImageView *newView =  [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    newView = fvImageView;
    if ( FlipType == @"V"){
        newView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1, 1);
    } else if ( FlipType == @"H"){
        newView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, -1);
    }else if ( FlipType == @"VH"){
        newView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1, -1);   
    }else if ( FlipType == @"N"){
        newView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, 1);
    }
    return newView;
    [newView release]; newView= nil;
}
```

Thanks for any help you can give!

Comment: I have updated the code Thanks RakeshNSS! 

I still do not know way I can not do it two times in a row. I would like to be able to flip back and forth.

Comment: I just checked and if I save the image it is not flipping the image only the View. I need to flip the image.

Comment: use `return [newView autorelease];` because your release after the return wont fire.

Answer (score 0):

The image is not flipped because, you releases image

```
[newView release];
```

then make it nil

```
newView= nil;
```

and then returns

```
return newView;
```

The result is you returns an nil value after doing some operations. I think it is just enough to make change on "fvImageView" object, which you passes as argument of the function.

Comment: Thanks! I should have seen that. 

Now that I have that part working  it still will not let me do it two times in a row. I want to be able to flip it back and forth with out it keeping the state of the flip.  Any thoughts?